# Invalid_request: Missing authority: file:// in AngularJS with Satellizer

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, authorize, satellizer

I am trying to use [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) to authorize with a Google account. When I click login, a popup appears showing this:

> **Invalid parameter**
>
> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing authority: file://
>
> Request Details:
>
> scope=openid profile email
>
> response_type=code
>
> redirect_uri=file://
>
> display=popup
>
> client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1: My Source Code**

***index.html***

```
<script src="lib/satellizer/satellizer.js"></script>
```

***app.js***

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$authProvider) {
     $authProvider.google({
      clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
     });
    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        controller: 'AppController'
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "views/login.html",
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})
```

and ***loginController.js***

```
.controller('LoginController', function($scope,$auth) {
    $scope.authenticate = function(provider) {
      $auth.authenticate(provider);
   };
});
```

Comment: Please share some of your code and/or provide more details.

Comment: Can anyone help me out